# Okta: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'System.String'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, okta

I'm building an app using Okta for authentication, but the API requests will always return a 500 error. I use `@okta/okta-react` to get the access token, but when sending in the Authorization header (`Bearer {accessToken}`) the server is unable to handle it.

The server replies with the following error for every request.

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[3]
      Exception occurred while processing message.
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'System.String'.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20807: Unable to retrieve document from: 'System.String'. HttpResponseMessage: 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage', HttpResponseMessage.Content: 'System.String'.
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.GetAsync(String address, IDocumentRetriever retriever, CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
```

I'm using the Okta.AspNetCore package for the configuration. My startup class has

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = OktaDefaults.ApiAuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OktaDefaults.ApiAuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = OktaDefaults.ApiAuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddOktaWebApi(new OktaWebApiOptions()
    {
        OktaDomain = Configuration["Okta:Authority"],
    });

services.AddAuthorization();
services.AddControllersWithViews();

...
}
```

and

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => ...
}
```

I've done a lot of searching around for answers, but most of them are similar, but not the same issue. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your `Configure` method is missing the call to `app.UseIdentityServer()`.

Comment: The issue with that, is that I was following https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/protect-your-api/aspnetcore3/before-you-begin/ and nowhere in there does it even mention IdentityServer. Along with that, it's an additional package that needs to be installed, which also was not mentioned.

Comment: One thing to be careful of is when using the middleware the order that they're declared is important. I had this error because I didn't use `app.UseAuthentication();` first then `app.UseAuthorization();` second. If these are in the wrong order you'll get the error: ` System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: `https://org.oktapreview.com/oauth2/aus17ct73zmZrZjbh0h8/.well-known/openid-configuration'.`